# Create Clusters of Rows in a Database based on similarities

Tags: database, cluster-analysis, vector-database

I am designing a system that takes student's modules and groups them together in classes based on their department and subjects chosen.

Let's for example take the following table:

| Student ID | Department | Choice 1 | Choice 2 | Choice 3 | Choice 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Languages** | English | Literature | Spanish | Italian |
| 2 | **Languages** | English | Literature | Spanish | Italian |
| 3 | **Languages** | English | Literature | Spanish | German |
| 4 | **Languages** | English | Literature | Spanish | French |
| 5 | **Science** | Math | Physics | Chemistry | Biology |
| 6 | **Science** | Math | Physics | Chemistry | Computing |

Let's say that each class can have 2 students.

With the above example 3 classes need to be created (1,2), (3,4) and (5,6).
(Note: students grouped together must be on the same department)

Can you give me hints how to design the database so it can allow for a number of groups/cluster to be created. The application gonna be really big with a lot of entries.

I thought of using a Vector Database for this but I am not sure if it is the best option

I would appreciate any helpful hints, links or books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say you will have a lot of data and you might need vector capabilities, then Cassandra would make sense. You could start now on the free tier of AstraDB which is a managed cassandra service.

The denormalized data-model would have 3 tables and look like this:

First table to read student information

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student_by_ID (
    Student_ID UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    Department TEXT,
    Choices LIST<TEXT>
);
```

Note if the number of choice will always be 4, then create 4 columns (choice1, choice2...)

Second table would allow you to retrieve a classe per id. Adding `student_ID` as a clustering column allow you to retrieve easly all the students for a given class.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classe_by_ID (
    Class_ID UUID,
    Student_ID UUID,
    Department TEXT,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (Class_ID, Student_ID)
);
```

Then we could have a last table for departments

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Department_by_ID (
    Department_Name TEXT,
    Class_ID UUID,
    PRIMARY KEY (Department_Name, Class_ID)
);
```

Astra has vector search capabilities (that will be in Cassandra 5.0) so you can add `vector` type attribute to your tables to perform similarity search on it. (check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSEl6deX2lU))